# Get error in Angular 7 ./src/app/app.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

In new installed Angular I changed
**app.components.ts** file like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: `<h1>Some Information</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';
}
```

But after compiling I am getting error

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

My app directory contains only two files app.component.ts and app.module.ts

Where is the problem ?

What is a right way to create component with inline template ?

Comment: Change `templateUrl` to `template`, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue that I see in your code is using `templateUrl` while you are providing the actual template
so instead of `templateUrl` use `template`